# Java write Registry with partially elevating / subprogram

Tags: java, windows, drag-and-drop, uac

My Java program uses the Windows Registry to store some values. (and yes, this cannot be done differently)

The problem is that I implemented a Drag and Drop Feature, but Windows does not allow drag and drop if a process is elevated, and the drag source is not.

Like dragging a folder from the Windows Explorer to the Program.

Now my Question is, is it possible to partially elevate my program, or use a subprogram that is elevated, and passes the values to the main program somehow?

And yes, I know that the explorer can be elevated as well, but no user has this by default.

Comment: Simply answer: yes it is possible to have a sub-app or to call a script with elevated permissions to complete registry tasks. Depending on what you are dragging and dropping you could do this any number of ways, the best option is likely via a socket connection or running a script that passes the parameters you need to the registry, or a cheap and nasty way might be via a text file in a directory that both programmes know about.

Comment: with socket connection you mean, having a 2nd application that would run as admin and does the registry part, which connects via a serversocket to the main application?

Comment: Yes, a socket connection it is one of the better ways to pass data between applications.

Comment: Im just wondering, since I want to pack my program into an EXE with launch4j, how I would include a 2nd jar that doesnt get elevated

Comment: actually wait, I will just use a folder for my program lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used solution:

Main Application is launched, creates a ServerSocket, then starts the Helper Application, which is wrapped in an .exe, which requests Admin privileges on start.

Meanwhile, the main app waits for the Helper to connect via a Socket, the Helper than sends all read values from the registry via an ObjectOutputStream.

The Helper application stay in while(true) and waits for further instructions from the main app, if the main app is shutdown, it will send an "exit" command to the Helper, the helper will then shutdown.